# PHP hash password compatible with Java hashing

Tags: java, php, hash, password-encryption

I am working on an application in java that requires a user to login with an account made on website, I am hashing the password with "PASSWORD_DEFAULT" but i am willing to change this as I know it is the problem. The java application will be sending the entered username and password and comparing it to the ones in the database. Is there a better hashing algorithm that is shared on both java and php for me to be able to compare the same password? I really want this to be secure for users and really dont want to ever store anything in plaintext.

Comment: Will your Java application actually be reading the database directly? If so, you can extract the hashing algorithm and salt from PHP's hashed password and apply that in the Java code. Or you could just ask the server to do it for you and use PHP for all the hashing.